# Method to get keys from array

Tags: c#, arrays

What is the equivalent C# syntax of this PHP script ?:

```
<?php
$arr = array("linux", "windows", "linux", "linux", "windows", "mac os", "unix", "mac os");
$unique = array_unique($arr);
foreach($unique as $key=>$value){
    echo $key."\n";
}
?>
```

the result of above code is:

```
0
1
5
6
```

so, the duplicates of the array are removed and then the keys of the array are displayed. I could only display the values of array:

```
string[] arr = { "linux", "windows", "linux", "linux", "windows", "mac os", "unix", "mac os" };
string[] uniq = arr.Distinct().ToArray();
foreach (string unik in uniq)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(unik+"\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with Linq fairly easily:

```
var indices = arr.Distinct()
                 .Select(s => Array.IndexOf(arr,s));

foreach (int i in indices)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(i+"\r\n");
}
```

or to include the value *and* the index:

```
var indices = arr.Distinct()
                 .Select(s => new {s, i = Array.IndexOf(arr,s)});

foreach (var si in indices)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(string.Format({0}: {1}\n", si.i, si.s));
}
```

If performance is a concern a more efficient (though harder to understand) version would be:

```
var indices = arr.Select((s, i) => new {s, i})  // select the value and the index
                 .GroupBy(si => si.s)           // group by the value
                 .Select(g => g.First());       // get the first value and index

foreach (var si in indices)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(string.Format({0}: {1}\n", si.i, si.s));
}
```

Comment: Won't `Distinct()` cause the indexes to shift from the original array?

Comment: This searches through the array for each index. It's O(n^2) when you can do this in O(n).

Comment: @PinnyM No - `Distinct` does not affect the original array in any way.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi which for 10 values should not be a problem.  But to be fair I'll add a more performant version.

Comment: I don't believe Array has an IndexOf(). List does, but not System.Array. You'll need to use `Array.IndexOf(arr, s)`.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
        string[] arr = { "linux", "windows", "linux", "linux", "windows", "mac os", "unix", "mac os" };
        string[] uniq = new string[0];
        string[] keys = new string[0];


        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (uniq.Contains(arr[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                uniq = uniq.Concat(new string[] { arr[i] }).ToArray();
                keys = keys.Concat(new string[] { i + "" }).ToArray();
            }
        }

        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            textBox1.Append(key + "\r\n");
        }
```

Comment: Instead of an array you want a Dictionary. Then both `Contains` and adding keys/values are O(1) instead of O(n). You probably don't want to append to an array like that anyway, just use a list (or in this case another collection) to begin with.

Comment: It works in `List` collection also. I just want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: It works, but it is going to get slower and slower as the list gets bigger and bigger at a exponential rate.

Answer (score 0):

Here a LinQ solution - res contains the index of the first occurence in the "arr" string array :

```
string[] arr = { "linux", "windows", "linux", "linux", "windows", "mac os", "unix", "mac os" };

var res = arr.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
          .ToDictionary(pair => pair.index, pair => pair.value)
          .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
          .Select(x => x.First().Key);

foreach (int i in res)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(i+"\r\n");
}
```